# Line break after output in Powershell or Terminal

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to have a line break after the output in Powershell, or in Windows Terminal?

[image]

In my profile I added `Write-Host` but then there is a line break before the prompt including the first line (when terminal starts) which I don't want:

```
function prompt
{
  Write-Host
  Write-Host
}
```

[image]

I tried a conditional but it doesn't work:

```
function prompt
{
  $first = $true
  if ($first) {$first = $false}
  else {Write-Host}
  Write-Host
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can do something with the cursorposition, and do not add an empty line on the first line of the screen? (`$host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.Y -eq 0`), but I do not have the need, nor the skills, to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To prevent the initial prompt after startup from printing empty lines, check if the session's command history is empty, using [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history).
- To additionally prevent unwanted empty lines after clearing the screen (e.g. with [`Clear-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Clear-Host)), you can test the index of the current line of the cursor with `$host.ui.rawUI.cursorPosition.Y`, as suggested by [Luuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724039/luuk), or, more simply in a console (terminal), with `[Console]::CursorTop`:

```bash
function prompt { 
  if ([Console]::CursorTop -gt 0 -and (Get-History -Count 1)) { 
    Write-Host "`n" 
  } else { # initial prompt or after clearing the screen
    '' 
  } 
}
```

Note:

- The approach relies on the fact that PowerShell prints its *default* prompt string, `PS>`, if the prompt function produces either *no* or *empty* output to the [success stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), which happens *after* any (by definition success-stream-bypassing) output from [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) has printed.
- If you simply want to emit an empty line in combination with the *current* `prompt` function, use the following:

```bash
$function:prompt = @"
  if ([Console]::CursorTop -gt 0 -and (Get-History -Count 1)) { 
    Write-Host "`n" 
  } 
  $function:prompt
"@
```

Comment: The `if ([Console]::CursorTop -gt 0) {Write-Host}` part is what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Edit: (might still not get the question) but this will add an extra line break

```
Write-Host "Hellow World!`n"
```

If this is related to starting a new powershell window, try `Clear-Host` at the top of your profile script

Comment: How this adds a line break after output?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misread that you got an unwanted line break. You have no Read-Host in the sample code. You can add `n for a new line, but will still get colon and space on the new line

Comment: I already use `cls` in my profile but it doesn't clear the line break.